# Mathematic cannot evaluate this integral. Why?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica will evaluate this integral:

$$\int_1^x\frac{1}{(1+C_1(\eta)(-1+x))^3}dx$$

but not this one:

$$
\int_1^x\frac{1}{(1+C_1(\eta)(-1+x)+C_2(\eta)(-1+x)^2)^3}dx
$$

I'm trying to solve this, and it is really holding me up. Any ideas why mathematica just hangs on trying to evaluate this?

Here is the Mathematica code:

```
ga = x/(1 + C*(x - 1) + D*(x - 1)*(x - 1))^3;
normconditiona = ga *1/x;
Integrate[normconditiona, {x, 1, x}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the Mathematica code that you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: @mikado sure just added it

Comment: Don't have *Mathematica* on this computer to check, but is $\{x,1,x\}$ allowed as the second argument to `Integrate[]`?

Comment: maybe it looks werid in that. basically im just integrating normcondtiona from 1 to x

Comment: My complaint is that the upper limit of the integral is the same as the variable of integration.  I don't know the answer, that's why I asked.  Anybody?

Comment: @mjw Integrate[1/(1 + c1 (x - 1))^3, {x, 1, x}] works fine, i.e. it returns ConditionalExpression[1/(2 c1) - 1/(2 c1 (1 + c1 (-1 + x))^2), 
 Re[c1 - c1 x] < 1 || c1 - c1 x \[NotElement] Reals]

Comment: @Goran,  Thanks!

Comment: sorry just make the upper limit Xm

Comment: With this code:`ga = x/(1 + c*(x - 1) + d*(x - 1)*(x - 1))^3;
normconditiona = ga*1/x;
Integrate[normconditiona, {x, 1, x}, 
 Assumptions -> {c > 0, d > 0, x > 1}]` works fine on MMA 12.0.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, and noting there are poles at

```
x /. Solve[Denominator@normconditiona == 0, x]
```

> {(-c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d] + 2 d)/(2 d), (-c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d] + 2 d)/(
>    2 d), (-c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d] + 2 d)/(
>    2 d), (-c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d] + 2 d)/(
>    2 d), (-c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d] + 2 d)/(
>    2 d), (-c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d] + 2 d)/(2 d)}

we can use the [`PrincipalValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrincipalValue.html) option to yield

```
Integrate[normconditiona /. x -> xp, {xp, 1, x}, PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> (c | d) ∈ Reals]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(-1 + x) DirectedInfinity[-(Sign[d]/
>       Sign[-1 + x]^2)], (c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d])/(2 d - 2 d x) ∈ 
>      Reals && (c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 d])/(2 d - 2 d x) ∈ Reals]

Comment: I'm not really sure what this is giving me. when i run it, i get this: ConditionalExpression[(-1 + x) DirectedInfinity[-(1/Sign[C])], 
 Im[x] == 0 && ((Re[x] < 
       1 && (C == 4 || (Im[C] == 0 && Re[C] > 4))) || (Im[C] == 0 && 
      Re[C] < 0 && Re[x] > 1))]